# How to inscribe a quadrilateral in a circle?

Tags: geometry

In the case of the isosceles trapezoid, I have seen drawings in which its longest base is always the diameter of the circumference. But, how can I know that the longest base will match the diameter? You could tell me: Well, you do it at your convenience. Well, suppose I choose the base of the isosceles trapezoid as diameter, but is there a problem now, how can I be sure that the other two vertices will belong to the circumference?

So my question is,

If I have a quadrilateral, that it fulfills the condition of supplementary opposites angles, how do I know when one side of it will coincide with the diameter, or with the radius? For example, at first sight a square will never coincide with the diameter, because otherwise its vertices will not be part of the circumference, but this is only intuition, however, what is the proof of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general you don't know.  Quadrilaterals of any shape can be constructed to be cyclic.  For isosceles trapezoid, just create a pair of chords parallel to each other and use the points of intersection with the circle to make the end points.

Comment: I am curious: what makes you think the longest base of an isosceles trapezoid is always (or even often) a diameter? You say you have seen drawings:  can you provide examples?  Because (as I wrote in my answer) it is definitely *not* typical.

Comment: When you draw the diagonals of isoceles trapezoid, the smaller segments formed are congruent, and the same with the largest. Also between the smaller segments, its formed a 90° angle that have the largest base of the trapezoid as a rope, so it must be a diameter.

Comment: can you see that in the point O(center of circumference) exist a 90° angle? is this only coincidence? or this happens in all isosceles trapezoid? See this image, for understand what im saying: https://goo.gl/images/n3nwRk

Answer (score 2):

Let $ABCD$ be inscribed in a circle. Then [Thales' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem) and its converse tell us that $AB$ coincides with a diameter of that circle if and only if $∠ACB$ is a right angle. (Note that $∠ACB$ and $∠ADB$ always have the same measure, by the [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem), so this is not as asymmetrical a condition as it sounds.)

In particular, if $ABCD$ is a square, $∠ACB$ will always have measure 45˚, and so will not be a right angle. Similarly, if $ABCD$ is a rectangle, the angle between any side and any diagonal is acute, and so no side of the rectangle can coincide with a diagonal of its circumscribed circle.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason at all to expect that the longest base of an isosceles trapezoid will be the diameter of the circumscribed circle, and indeed it is not usually the case.

What *is* the case is that the (common) perpendicular bisector of the two parallel bases must be a diameter of the circle.

In general, you can locate the center of the circumscribed circle for any cyclic quadrilateral by constructing the perpendicular bisectors of any two non-parallel sides and finding their intersection point.  So one way of answering your question is to construct perpendicular bisectors of two of the sides and see if they intersect on a third side.  If they do, that third side is the diameter of the circle.

Comment: What do you mean by perpendicular bisector? Can you provide a example, please?